# React state does not change after setState is being called

Tags: reactjs, react-state

I am fairly new to React and trying to understand the concept of states. I am trying to have a set of input fields right after one another like a terminal

The page component looks like this

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import NewLine from "./newLine";

export class Page extends Component {
    state = {
        numberOfLine: 0,
        lines: [{ value: "", id: 0 }]
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="terminal">
                    <p className="prompt">
                        Hey there! This is a pre rendered line.
                    </p>
                    {this.state.lines.map(l => (
                        <NewLine
                            key={this.state.numberOfLine}
                            handelWhatever={this.handelWhatever}
                            line={l}
                        ></NewLine>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }



    handelWhatever = (string_value, LId) => {
        console.log(string_value, lId);
        this.setState(
            {
                lines: [
                    ...this.state.lines.filter(line => line.id !== lId),
                    { value: string_value, id: lId}
                ]
            },
            () => this.handleClick()
        );
    };

    // Adding a new line after a click 
    handleClick = event => {
        const num = this.state.numberOfLine + 1;
        this.setState({
            numberOfLine: num,
            lines: [...this.state.lines, { value: "", id: num }]
        });
    };
}

export default Page;
```

and my `NewLine` component looks like this

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export class NewLine extends Component {
    state = {
        id: this.props.line.id,
        value: this.props.line.value,
        displayInput: true
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <p className=output>
                    {this.state.displayInput && (
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            className="here"
                            value={this.state.value}
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                            onKeyDown={this.handelEnter}
                        />
                    )}
                    {this.state.value}
                </p>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }

    handleChange = event => {
        this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
    };

    handelEnter = event => {
        if (event.key === "Enter") {
            this.setState({displayInput : false})
            this.props.handelWhatever(event.target.value, this.state.id);
    }
    };

}

export default NewLine;
```

When I enter the "something" in the input it should make a NewLine component and delete the input from the previous one so that user can type on the newly rendered line that is why I have bool in the New Line state, but the bool does not change even though the `console.log("Did bool change")` prints , Also i gave setState a callback function

```
this.setState({ displayInput: false }, () => console.log(this.state))
```

it updates the state and `displayInput` to be false but in the react console it still shows displayInput to be true

Or is there another way of doing this?

Thank you for the help 
Cheers

Comment: `Did bool change` is printed out from `setState`'s callback; at that point the state *has* changed. It has *not* changed in the rest of `handleEnter` yet because `setState` is async--that's one reason the callback function exists.

Comment: Try using a callback for the specific state value. `this.setState({ displayInput: false }, () => {
      console.log("displayInput boolean ---> ", this.state.displayInput);
    });`

Comment: if you just want to confirm print state in componentDidUpdate method. You can print prev state and current state as well to compare.

Comment: I am thinking of passing a bool to NewLine and then change this.props.bool in the new line. Is that a right approach?

Comment: @DaveNewton I am now passing it as a prop because it was not updating as setstate was async, but i am ran into a new problem. Please see the Update in the initial post. Thank you

Comment: @motorleaf (1) If it's a new problem then it's a new question. (2) `setState` is always async; if you need to access that value *from state* "immediately" after setting it then you should do so from the callback: this is just how React works. Trying to work around it by creating awkward structures isn't the best approach.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thank you for the help! For the new problem should I post a new question or just edit this one?

Comment: I would post new one so if someone run into this issue they can take help.

Comment: @Garry Thank you i will re-edit this one to the original post and post a new question